# Working with nested formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested, logic

I'm new to formulas and I need a good one that checks multiple criteria from different columns to return a result.  For example, if column `B` contains `4540` or `2750` or `4848` and column `I` contains either `9a 519` or `9A 521` for example return `Capex`, otherwise `""`.

I've given it a go as follows:

```
=IF(
    OR(
       AND(
           OR(B22606=4540, B22606=4543, B22606=4586, B22606=4847, B22606=4848, B22606=4993,
              B22606=4996, B22606=5007, B22606=5008, B22606=5011 ,B22606=5034),
           I22606="9A - 517"),
       I22606="9A - 518", I22606="9A - 519", I22606="9A - 521", I22606="9A - 522",
       I22606="9A - 550", I22606="9A - 526", I22606="9A - 528", I22606="9A - 530",
       I22606="9A - 551", I22606="9A - 591", I22606="9A - 552", I22606="9A - 531",
       I22606="9A - 553", I22606="9A - 524", I22606="9A - 525"),
    "CAPEX","")
```

but it doesn't quite work. Is there a better way to tackle this?

Comment: Have you tried using `Evaluate Formula` (in the `FORMULAS` tab of the ribbon)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Array with `OR`

```
OR(B22606 = {4540,4543,4586,4847,4848,4993,4996,5007,5011,5034})
```

and

```
OR(I22606 = {"9A - 517","9A - 518","9A - 519",...})
```

So:

```
 =IF(AND(OR(B22606 = {4540,4543,4586,4847,4848,4993,4996,5007,5011,5034}),OR(I22606 = {"9A - 517","9A - 518","9A - 519"}),"CAPEX","")
```